# xcode 8.1 Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

**In xcode 8.1 I am getting this error while Building the Project**

```
ld: 9 duplicate symbols for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

In Xcode 8.1 I didn't find any settings for to set the architecture.

How can i fix this issue???

Comment: can you add some addiional errors

Comment: check if you `#import` a `.m` file instead of the `.h` file.

Comment: clean your project and build again.

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik.....its fixed...Some of the methods i have used twice, that is the problem

Comment: @UmairAfzal...Its Fixed...Thanks

Comment: @abhi1992...its fixed..thanks